# How to make use of Function Apps for Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: node.js, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

So I've been trying to generate a small function app (in JS) that responds to a message sent to the Azure IoT Hub. The output is a simple console log. However, I am unable to load the event hub compatible end point of the IoT Hub as the trigger (the only option available is to create a new Event Hub). How do I proceed? The code for the device to send to Azure' IoT Hub is working and I am able to view the messages via the Device Explorer tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new Event Hub Connection and use the Event Hub-Compatible endpoint from the Iot Hub Messaging section. 
But you need to change it to match the service bus connection string format -
"Endpoint=[your iot hub compatible end point];SharedAccessKeyName=[your key name];SharedAccessKey=[your key];EntityPath=[your event hub compatible name]"

key name and key can be taken from the "Shared access policy" section.

Good Luck

Comment: still having issues. This time I get the following error message:
"Management operation failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature..."
When you refer to the service bus connection format, do you mean the textbox that asks for the connection string? And can the connection name be anything or should it be the IoT Hub's event hub compatible name? @shachar

Comment: @ChiragS , yes, the service bus connection format should be added in the "Event Hub Connection" in the connection string text box, under the connection string name. the connection name can be anything you want, it's just an identifier.

Comment: I see. My mistake was that I was using the shared access key specified for the device. Doesn't work unless its its the service key